# Would enabling VirtualBox's "host i/o caching" option compromise much anonymity on your Whonix VM?

Tags: whonix

I'm kind of a newb with VBox and trying to boost my VM performance any way possible to make it more useful, but my guess would be not to mess with much of the default settings in the Whonix workstation or gateway besides the RAM and CPU, right?

I found the host I/O caching to be of some help for performance but I wonder how big of a vulnerability the data exchange is. Is the data on the host an anonymity concern? Does it have any sensitive information? Looks like bidirectional copy/paste is enabled by default and I don't see how that would be much different...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not compromising your security at all: if your virtualization host os pwn'ed and you're not using quite a layer of security like a LUKS + AMD SEV or Intel corresponding stack for a secure VM running - you're doomed. The host caching feature *is* handy when you do have an UPS that can perform a safe shutdown via USB connection *or* a network management card. In this case you do have a good - or even a great - performance boost. You can also run it on a laptop that will do a safe shutdown when the battery power is near depletion. Even a simple UPS with a USB connector costs like a 100USD, so don't be too savvy ;)